# What happens to reputation earned after the 200 rep limit is exceeded?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

What happens to all the extra rep. earned after the 200 daily cap is exceeded? (With the exception of bounties and accepted answers of course.) Does it just "disappear"? Do you gain it the next UTC day? What does happen to it?

Comment: Yes, it's gone forever.

Comment: That (the preceding comment) is what *they* want you to think. In fact, the extra reputation goes into a heavily guarded reputation storage at an undisclosed location in New Jersey.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier I always wondered where Jon Skeet got his rep- Oh crap, he's here! ***radio static***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You stop getting rep from upvotes till tomorrow (in UTC), it just disappears. However accepts and bounties still bring you rep - they are exempt from the rep cap. Look at my rep for June 28 (two days ago).